# Are Passbook Passes Available Outside the Sandbox?

Tags: iphone, wallet

With Third Party software, or manually mounting the iPhone to your computer, it's possible to access a limited amount of information. Music, Photos, and App Data. Without breaking the Sandbox, you can never get to the OS itself, and certain data stores.

Are Passbook Passes accessible within this Sandbox? I'd be awesome to see what data is actually contained within them.

Comment: Is your objective to autopsy a Passbook pass?

Comment: The ones loaded directly onto the phone, yes. I've looked at Passbook Passes generated by [passsource.com](http://passsource.com), but I'm curious to look at the official ones.

Comment: Well, the passes generated by pass source are authentic and the only thing they lack is an official identifier from Apple, so you would have nothing to explore in a real one.

Comment: Satisfy my curiosity :).

Comment: Oh, okay… But passes are encrypted on the phone, how will you decrypt them?

Comment: This question isn't asking how do I read passes, it's asking if they're located somewhere I can access without jailbreaking. If you had answered that question, you'd have positive rep and we wouldn't be back-and-forth'ing like this.

Comment: Haha… but still, everything that’s encrypted is outside the box. Contacts. You can’t access contacts when the iPhone is mounted, right? (Speculation)

Comment: I have admittedly not gone after the raw Contact data, but no, everything is not encrypted. I can access my Safari cache, a bunch of plists, all my music, and all my photos. Given the implementation of Passbook Passes, I assumed they would be publicly accessible as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote to Macroplant, who make the [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) utility that I bought some time ago, and they pointed me to the fact that Passbook Cards are available in the backup data.

When using iExplorer, they're located in the 'Backup Explorer' section, under `HomeDomain/Library/Passes/Cards`, the Backup Explorer section is apparently a logical mapping of `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`.

That's good enough for me, since data is routinely backed up. I can backup and instantly access my current cards.

Thank you Mike, on the Macroplant Support Team!